# AWS Elasticbeanstalk Multi Container - instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Beanstalk is throwing below errors during deployment -

`- The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-0a2f60975b252747d].`

`- Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, TimedOut: 1].`

`- Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0a2f60975b252747d'. Aborting the operation.`

This happens every 2nd day, i don't change anything at all. It takes lot of time & gets timed out at the end. Unable to find a permanent solution for this.

Even "restart appserver" from console also doesn't work. EC2 instance seems to be healthy enough, application works fine & i can do SSH etc. However rebooting the EC2 instance bring it back to normal.
Did anyone else faced this problem, what can be done to find a permanent solution? Also how things will work in case of Autoscaling, this can cause major problems in Production?

Answer (score 2):

I had a semi-similar issue with elasticbeanstalk. Turns out I was using an old `t1.micro` instance that is not recommended for use anymore. I upgraded the instance to a `t2.small` and I no longer get timeouts and my deployments are much faster and more stable.

Comment: After trying rebuild, create new instance, etc... This was the only solution that worked for me. Very thanks!